# Populate datagrid with objects WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have multiple instances of different types of model classes.

In the constructor i add them to an "global" list of instances:

```
ProcessObjects.Instance.AddProcessObject(name, this);
```

So basicly i want to be able to have an ObservableCollection of generic type.
When i select an item in a datagrid i would like to be able to display the contents/properties of that object in another datagrid.

```
    <DataGrid Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding RunTimeObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"/>
    <DataGrid Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObject}"/>
```

What common type can i convert the model class into to achieve my goal of populating the datagrid automaticly based on the available properties in the selected item?

Comment: If the purpose of doing this is to update another datagrid then can't you do this in the frontend itself, using angular or just Javascript?

Anyway, If your Model classes are similar then creating a base class and creating sub classes by inheritance will help you in saving the instances of the sub classes under a common base class. Does this help you?

Comment: I have thought about creating the a base class. The problem is that there are some properties which they dont share which are also relevant to the user. Was hoping that there was some kind of way that the datagrid could read the public properties of the basic object an display them automaticly.

Comment: How about managing this in the frontend (e.x., by binding properties using angularjs or Javascript)?

Comment: It was supposed to be an simple wpf desktop app. :)

Comment: oops! that was a stupid question... sorry!